# JSON formula for column to get the earliest date from two or more other date columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, microsoft

Wanting to use a separate column that defines which date from two other columns is the earliest.

Comment: How many date columns you want to compare in the condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [MIN function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/min-function-61635d12-920f-4ce2-a70f-96f202dcc152) in separate calculated column to compare multiple date columns and return the earliest date:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much - worked perfectly :)